# grub error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: grub

I am getting the following grub error: `attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'`.

Is there any way to fix this error? I can't boot into Debian because of this.

**Partitions:**

```
SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) - 250.1 GB ATA WDC WD2500BEVE-0
    #1 Primary 249.0 GB B ext4
    #5 logical 1.1 GB F swap swap
SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sdb) - 7.8 GB USB Flash Memory
    #1 primary 7.8 BG B fat32
```

SCSI3 is a USB device to load in some firmware needed for the install of Debian.

Comment: You would at the very least need to provide your grub configuration and partition information to get any valuable answer.

Comment: @JuliePelletier As I stated, I am new to Linux and everything surrounding this, and as I don't seem to be able to boot into any OS, I don't know how to access this information, though I can add the partition information, so I'll do that

Comment: Obviously, if you can not boot from this setup, you'll need to boot from a USB key or other device to verify and correct your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're usign debian,  it will be very easy to recover grub, using the installation CD.

Boot the install Debian CD and select Advanced options -> Rescue Mode
There you will have options to reinstall grub or to go to a chroot shell, and reinstall grub using:

```
grub-mkdevicemap  
grub-install /dev/sda  
update-grub
```